# ForeignKey, show values in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two classes:

```
class People
    name = CharField()

class Equipment
    name = Charfield()
    responsible = ForeignKey(People)
```

and view:

```
def persone_detail(request, tab_number):
    return direct_to_template(request, 'person.html', {
       'persone': Peoples.objects.filter(tab_number=tab_number)
```

How can I show in template the **name** from **equipment**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By following the reverse relationship to Equipment:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

```
{% for person in persone %}
    Person: {{ person.name }}
    {% for equipment in person.equipment_set.all %}
        Equipment: {{ equipment.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```